# Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual boot installation only shows Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, usb-drive, windows-10

I installed the latest version of Ubuntu in dual boot using the installation menu. I installed off of a thumb drive. Ubuntu works on laptop but Windows boot option is missing. Data and partition show up as a second drive under Ubuntu. I am new to this and don't know how to fix this. Windows is still there I think but it won't dual boot; only Ubuntu shows up. I used pendrive to create the USB drive using a Ubuntu iso.

Comment: Do you see a GRUB Menu showing Ubuntu, Ubuntu Failsafe or something like this, followed by Windows? Please clarify that and also confirm you're not booting from the USB disk and has removed the same and booting from hdd.

Comment: Try boot repair this will help to repair your grub and shows the dual boot option.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to my with linux mint, I fixed it with boot repair.
to install it open the terminal and paste this

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

click in the recommended repair, and that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact thing that happened to me. The Windows partitions still remained, but the dual-boot menu only showed Ubuntu. For me, waiting it out (4 days or so) seemed to work, and Windows appeared after that. Maybe I unknowingly did something to fix it, idk